# Formatting an SSRS report to not look terrible in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I've got an SSRS report that I'm dynamically writing to an HTML page.  The report looks great in IE, but it keeps none of its formatting in Firefox.

I've done a bit of research on this, and found that I can insert rectangles inside of all of my matrix data fields, which will keep the formatting.  This seems to me like a lot of work for something that I'm sure someone has solved more elegantly before.

I've also tried messing with the CanGrow and CanShrink properties of the matrix.  No help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice discussion [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1232493/2228181.aspx) and [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1174296/1973791.aspx#1973791)

Some highlights from that discussion:

- Try setting the CanGrow = false; for the textbox.
- Are the problems with the display?  With the width and height lost?  Look at this [thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1194312/2063445.aspx#2063445)
- CSS file entry as follows:

**make this change in the css file**

```
/* Fix report IFRAME height for Firefox */
.DocMapAndReportFrame
{
 min-height: 860px;
}
```

Comment: CanGrow is false by default.  The problem is with the display, as the width is lost.  I realized that I could hack some classes onto the generated table, but I didn't want to do that.

The thread you mentioned is very helpful and will likely lead me to a solution.  If it doesn't work, I'll hack it

Comment: Joe, please let use know what worked, maybe you can add it to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the form height to 95% in Pages > ReportViewer.aspx