# How to get rid of unwanted scrollbars in an SSRS reports within an Iframe and increased Windows display size?

Tags: firefox, windows-7, iframe, reporting-services, font-size

We run an web-app with built-in SSRS reports, which are integrated via an Iframe.

A user has set her display percentage to 150% in Windows 7.
(Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display).

She is displaying the webpage with the report in Firefox and she has to scroll horizontally and vertically within the Iframe to view the whole report.

I managed to get some screenshots

- no scrollbars in Firefox 
  with a display percentage set to 100% set in Windows 7
  http://screencast.com/t/MGM3MmQzOTgt
- no scrollbars in IE8 (with display 150% set in Windows 7)
  http://screencast.com/t/ZjE3NGVj
- scrollbars in Firefox 
  with a display percentage set to 150% set in Windows 7
  http://screencast.com/t/ZmI1Yjkz

Somehow Iframe and SSRS don't seem to work together well, but how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two threads look particularly relevant:

[SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services: Reports are Compressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143410/sql-server-2005-reporting-services-reports-are-compressed)

[Formatting an SSRS report to not look terrible in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697568/formatting-an-ssrs-report-to-not-look-terrible-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add this if it may help someone.

I had this issue, and needed to remove toolbar and scroll bars. I ended up finding the entity, and setting it with another css file, then adding URL switches to call that css file.

If you create a new css file in the [[report server]]\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Styles folder and name it hideToolbar.css.

Then edit that file to include

```
    .ToolBarButtonsCell{display: none;}
    html{overflow:hidden;}
```

Then you can just use it in your URL like this example:

http://[[report server name or IP address]]/**ReportServer**/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fSharedReports%2f<>&rs:Command=Render&rc:stylesheet=hideToolBar

Make sure you're useing "ReportServer" versus "Reports" in the URL to get the desired result.